# How to convert from array of char to NSString in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I'm trying to read an input of type `NSString` from the user but I couldn't find the format specifier for `NSString`, I know that `%i` is for integer variables, but which one is for `NSString`?

As a result, I created an array of char, read the input from a user, but I couldn't convert it to `NSString` and XCode gives me as an output weird things like `ø¿_ÿ` and sometimes `(null)` I have used many string encodings like (none of them worked):

```
   NSASCIIStringEncoding 

   NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding 

   NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding 

   NSUTF8StringEncoding 

   NSISOLatin1StringEncoding 

   NSSymbolStringEncoding 

   NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding

   NSShiftJISStringEncoding 

   NSISOLatin2StringEncoding

   NSUnicodeStringEncoding 

   NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding 

   NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding 

   NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding 

   NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding 

   NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding 

   NSISO2022JPStringEncoding 

   NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding

   NSUTF16StringEncoding 

   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding 

   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding 

   NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100

   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding 

   NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding 

   NSProprietaryStringEncoding
```

Could anyone tell me why? 
This is my code:

```
 //I have declared a class and called it Labtop
 Labtop *myLabtop;

        myLabtop = [[Labtop alloc] init];

       char input[30];
       NSLog(@"Hello,please enter which brand you will use this time:\n");
        input[29] = getchar();// read the input from the user

      NSString *b =[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:input encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];//convert from array char to NSString
      [myLabtop labtopBrand:b];//labtopBrand fund will print what the user has entered
```

The result is:

> Hello,please enter which brand you will use this time:
>
> MacBook //this is the user's input
>
> I will use  ø¿_ÿ//this what Xcode shows me as an output Program ended
>   with exit code: 0

Comment: Are you sure input holds anything useful? Maybe it is not set?

Answer (score 0):

Format specifier for NSString is %@

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems here. First off, `getchar()` returns one character, not a whole string. Second, this line:

```
    input[29] = getchar();// read the input from the user
```

Just assigns the last character in `input` to the character the user types, which probably isn’t what you want at all. Maybe you meant `gets()`? Except you really shouldn’t use that since it has no bounds checking, and you still wouldn’t want to assign the results to the thirtieth character in your array. Maybe look at `getline()` instead.

Also, you’ll probably want to specify `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Good luck, keep experimenting!